# Cannot format drive from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop-repair

A laptop suddenly stopped working and keeps on telling me to launch repair Wizard and then restarts again.

I am trying to just format the hard drive. I have burned a windows7.iso to a DVD and used <kbd>F12</kbd> to get a boot menu where I choose CD/DVD.

However I the system still starts from the broken installations and I get the same repair screen again. (Neither these work for me). It seems that the DVD that has the iso is not read correctly.

Is it a problem if the cd/dvd was burned by windows burner not a special burner?

What could be the problem?

Comment: Will the W7 dvd you made boot on any other PC?

Comment: Did you burn a DVD with the iso file on it, or did you burn the contents of the ISO file?

Answer (score 0):

It’s a little difficult to tell exactly what is happening. There are a few different phases to booting a computer and it’s to clear at what point the error messages you are getting are occurring. Is the screen that tells you to launch the Repair Wizard black text or blue graphics? Is there a mouse cursor? What happens when you run the Repair Wizard?

In any case, based on the symptoms you describe, there are a couple of things that you should check:

1. Examine the files on the DVD (eg, open it in another computer); what do you see? Do you see a single, large `windows7.iso` file or do you see a bunch of files and folders (eg `setup.exe`, `autorun.inf`, `boot`, `source`, etc)? If you only see the `.ISO` file, then you burned it wrong. The .ISO file *contains* the files that Windows needs to install from. You need to burn a DVD **image**, specifying the .ISO file as the *source*.
2. Do you see a prompt to boot from the disc like the one below when you restart? Did you press a key?

[image]

Comment: I do see the prompt in the image but when I press any key It says windows preparing files (progress bar) and then stuck on black screen with a working cursor.

Comment: Did you check the installation disc? Does the progress bar get to the end? Maybe it’s not stuck, just busy. Look at the hard-drive light on the case and listen carefully; does the LED flash or do you hear the drive making noise? Maybe it is having trouble with a piece of your hardware. When you reboot, can you press `F8` to boot into safe mode?